# AppCenter can't find Swift project

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, visual-studio-app-center

I am using Microsoft's AppCenter to distribute an app.
After connecting to a branch I receive an error page
[image]

I set the scheme of the app to shared as required. Anyone have any experience with similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you reach out to App Center support (via the chat bubble at bottom right of the portal). We can then look into details of your application. If it's something others can run into too, we can circle back and share what happened.

Comment: OK. I will try. Thank you.